# Snakemake producing wildly incoherent error when dryrunning

Tags: python-3.x, snakemake

I've spent the past year working on a project executed on a SLURM-managed cluster. Now we want to make our results reproducible and to do so, we're porting it to snakemake. However, I am learning it from scratch and it's giving me a headache.

Below is my code:

```
# module load python/3.7
# python -m venv ./venv
# source ./venv/bin/activate
# pip install snakemake
# snakemake --version

configfile: "config.yaml"
#localrules:
vcf=config["vcf"],
ncbiFiles=config["ncbiFiles"]
LC=config["leafcutter"]


rule all:
    input: ".prepare_phen_table.chkpnt"

rule filter_vcf:
    input:
        expand("{vcf}", vcf=config["vcf"]),
        expand("{ncbiFiles}", ncbiFiles=config["ncbiFiles"])
    output:
        expand("{ncbiFiles}/phg000830.v1.GTEx_WGS.genotype-calls-vcf.c1/GTExWGSGenotypeMatrixBiallelicOnly.HQ.vcf.gz", ncbiFiles=config["ncbiFiles"])
    shell:
        expand("sbatch --wait --export=vcf={vcf},outdir=$PWD src/sqtl_mapping/primary/sh/00a_bcftools_filter.sh", vcf=config["vcf"])

rule index_vcf:
    input:
        expand("{ncbiFiles}/phg000830.v1.GTEx_WGS.genotype-calls-vcf.c1/GTExWGSGenotypeMatrixBiallelicOnly.HQ.vcf.gz", ncbiFiles=config["ncbiFiles"])
    output:
        expand("{ncbiFiles}/phg000830.v1.GTEx_WGS.genotype-calls-vcf.c1/GTExWGSGenotypeMatrixBiallelicOnly.vcf.gz.tbi",ncbiFiles=config["ncbiFiles"]),
        expand("{ncbiFiles}/.index_vcf.chkpnt",ncbiFiles=config["ncbiFiles"])
    shell:
        expand("sbatch --export=outdir=$PWD src/sqtl_mapping/primary/sh/00b_index_vcf.sh;"
        "touch {ncbiFiles}/.index_vcf.chkpnt",ncbiFiles=config["ncbiFiles"])

rule junc_cluster:
    input:
        expand("{ncbiFiles}/.index_vcf.chkpnt", ncbiFiles=config["ncbiFiles"])
    output:
        ".junc_cluster.chkpnt"
    shell:
        "sbatch --wait src/sqtl_mapping/sh/01_junc_cluster.sh;"
        "touch .junc_cluster.chkpnt"

rule intron_clustering:
    input:
        ".junc_cluster.chkpnt"
    output:
        ".intron_clustering.chkpnt"
    shell:
        expand("sbatch --wait src/sqtl_mapping/sh/02_intronclustering.sh {LC};"
        "touch .intron_clustering.chkpnt;"
        "cd intronclustering/", LC=config["leafcutter"])

rule prepare_phen_table:
    input:
        LC,
        ".intron_clustering.chkpnt"
    output:
        ".prepare_phen_table.chkpnt"
    shell:
        expand("sbatch --wait src/sqtl_mapping/sh/03_prepare_phen_table.sh {LC};"
        "touch .prepare_phen_table.chkpnt",LC=config["leafcutter"])
```

Please assume the `config.yaml` is fine. When I call `snakemake -n`, I get the following error:

```
(venv) [aseyedi2@jhu.edu@rmccoy22-dev neand_sQTL]$ snakemake -n
Building DAG of jobs...
Job counts:
    count   jobs
    1   all
    1   index_vcf
    1   intron_clustering
    1   junc_cluster
    1   prepare_phen_table
    5

[Fri Aug 16 12:31:53 2019]
rule index_vcf:
    input: /scratch/groups/rmccoy22/Ne_sQTL/files/phg000830.v1.GTEx_WGS.genotype-calls-vcf.c1/GTExWGSGenotypeMatrixBiallelicOnly.HQ.vcf.gz
    output: /scratch/groups/rmccoy22/Ne_sQTL/files/phg000830.v1.GTEx_WGS.genotype-calls-vcf.c1/GTExWGSGenotypeMatrixBiallelicOnly.vcf.gz.tbi, /scratch/groups/rmccoy22/Ne_sQTL/files/.index_vcf.chkpnt
    jobid: 4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scratch/groups/rmccoy22/aseyedi2/neand_sQTL/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 547, in snakemake
    export_cwl=export_cwl)
  File "/scratch/groups/rmccoy22/aseyedi2/neand_sQTL/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 674, in execute
    success = scheduler.schedule()
  File "/scratch/groups/rmccoy22/aseyedi2/neand_sQTL/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/scheduler.py", line 278, in schedule
    self.run(job)
  File "/scratch/groups/rmccoy22/aseyedi2/neand_sQTL/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/scheduler.py", line 294, in run
    error_callback=self._error)
  File "/scratch/groups/rmccoy22/aseyedi2/neand_sQTL/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/executors.py", line 75, in run
    self._run(job)
  File "/scratch/groups/rmccoy22/aseyedi2/neand_sQTL/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/executors.py", line 86, in _run
    self.printjob(job)
  File "/scratch/groups/rmccoy22/aseyedi2/neand_sQTL/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/executors.py", line 92, in printjob
    job.log_info(skip_dynamic=True)
  File "/scratch/groups/rmccoy22/aseyedi2/neand_sQTL/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/jobs.py", line 825, in log_info
    logger.shellcmd(self.shellcmd, indent=indent)
  File "/scratch/groups/rmccoy22/aseyedi2/neand_sQTL/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/jobs.py", line 323, in shellcmd
    self.rule.shellcmd else None)
  File "/scratch/groups/rmccoy22/aseyedi2/neand_sQTL/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/jobs.py", line 732, in format_wildcards
    return format(string, **_variables)
  File "/scratch/groups/rmccoy22/aseyedi2/neand_sQTL/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/utils.py", line 378, in format
    return fmt.format(_pattern, *args, **variables)
  File "/software/apps/python/3.7/lib/python3.7/string.py", line 186, in format
    return self.vformat(format_string, args, kwargs)
  File "/software/apps/python/3.7/lib/python3.7/string.py", line 190, in vformat
    result, _ = self._vformat(format_string, args, kwargs, used_args, 2)
  File "/software/apps/python/3.7/lib/python3.7/string.py", line 200, in _vformat
    self.parse(format_string):
  File "/software/apps/python/3.7/lib/python3.7/string.py", line 284, in parse
    return _string.formatter_parser(format_string)
TypeError: expected str, got list
```

I have no idea what to make of it other than possibly that there is some sort of bug or incompatibility with what I'm trying to do.

Thank you for any help you can offer me.

Comment: I am on the phone so it's difficult to give a more elaborate answer. Concerning the expected str got list error: you misunderstand how snakemake wildcards work. Take a look again at the tutorial. You do not have to call expand on the shell 'attribute'. You can use the wildcard directly in the string (I believe as {wildcards.vcf}).

Comment: Btw take a look again how snakemake cluster execution works. You do not have to call sbatch in every shell command. The beauty of snakemake is that, as they call is, is environment agnostic. By using the --cluster command you can prepend the sbatch command, making the workflow work on both local machines and the cluster

Comment: And about the filter_vcf not being executed. Are you sure the output of that rule does not already exist? If files already exist snakemake does not try to recreate

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande but doesn't snakemake tell you that the output has been detected and the rule won't be executed? Here it's not even being counted in the DAG.

Comment: No it doesn't tell you, ánd it won't execute. Did you check if the file exists? If so, you can delete/rename it to see if at least that part works.

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande ok, that worked. I can get `filter_vcf` now.

Comment: Nice, I'll write a more elaborate answer somewhere in the weekend for the other issues if no one else picks up

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I decided to take the liberty to also give some *style* feedback while at it :). This is what I would make it (I ofcourse couldn't test it):

```
configfile: "config.yaml"


rule all:
    input: 
        ".prepare_phen_table.chkpnt"


rule filter_vcf:
    input:
        expand("{vcf}", vcf=config["vcf"]),
        expand("{ncbiFiles}", ncbiFiles=config["ncbiFiles"])
    output:
        expand("{ncbiFiles}/phg000830.v1.GTEx_WGS.genotype-calls-vcf.c1/GTExWGSGenotypeMatrixBiallelicOnly.HQ.vcf.gz", ncbiFiles=config["ncbiFiles"])
    shell:
        "src/sqtl_mapping/primary/sh/00a_bcftools_filter.sh"


rule index_vcf:
    input:
        expand("{ncbiFiles}/phg000830.v1.GTEx_WGS.genotype-calls-vcf.c1/GTExWGSGenotypeMatrixBiallelicOnly.HQ.vcf.gz", ncbiFiles=config["ncbiFiles"])
    output:
        expand("{ncbiFiles}/phg000830.v1.GTEx_WGS.genotype-calls-vcf.c1/GTExWGSGenotypeMatrixBiallelicOnly.vcf.gz.tbi",ncbiFiles=config["ncbiFiles"]),
        touch(expand("{ncbiFiles}/.index_vcf.chkpnt",ncbiFiles=config["ncbiFiles"]))
    shell:
        "src/sqtl_mapping/primary/sh/00b_index_vcf.sh"


rule junc_cluster:
    input:
        expand("{ncbiFiles}/.index_vcf.chkpnt", ncbiFiles=config["ncbiFiles"])
    output:
        touch(".junc_cluster.chkpnt")
    shell:
        "src/sqtl_mapping/sh/01_junc_cluster.sh"


rule intron_clustering:
    input:
        ".junc_cluster.chkpnt"
    output:
        touch(".intron_clustering.chkpnt")
    params:
        LC=config["leafcutter"]
    shell:
        "src/sqtl_mapping/sh/02_intronclustering.sh {params.LC}"


rule prepare_phen_table:
    input:
        config["leafcutter"],
        ".intron_clustering.chkpnt"
    output:
        touch(".prepare_phen_table.chkpnt")
    params:
        LC=config["leafcutter"]
    shell:
        "src/sqtl_mapping/sh/03_prepare_phen_table.sh {params.LC}"
```

Most importantly this should fix your issue that snakemake complains that it expects a string but gets a list. The expand function returns a list of all combinations, which in your case was a list of one long (but still a list and not a string). I just stored the LC in a param, instead of trying to fill its value by calling expand.

Second I changed your checkpoint touches to a cool [in-built function](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#flag-files) of snakemake.

Last but not least, I deleted all your sbatch calls. The idea of snakemake is that it can be executed on any platform. Local computers, and superclusters alike. If you hardcode the sbatch command it will only work on slurm clusters. If you want to execute your code on your local computer you just type

```
snakemake ...[params]
```

and if you want to run it on a slurm cluster all you have to change is

```
snakemake ...[params] --cluster "sbatch"
```

And snakemake will prepend the sbatch command to all your function calls. Easy! Take a look again at the [cluster docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html#cluster-configuration).

Make sure to take a look again at the snakemake docs and tutorial, so that you understand the idea/paradigm of snakemake. Probably my changes fix 90% of your issues, but need some small tinkering on your side in the end. Good luck!

Comment: Could I also just directly include the shell commands that I am calling in those scripts within the snakemake rules if I have a `cluster_config` file?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: take the contents of `src/sqtl_mapping/primary/sh/00a_bcftools_filter.sh` and put it in the `shell` directive instead of calling a script which contains the shell commands I would like to execute.

Comment: Yes, and it is very much encouraged to do so! I am not sure what the cluster_config has to do with it though..

Comment: The scripts that are being called have `#SBATCH` configuration flags in the header, so my thinking was that if I take the commands out of those scripts and instead place them within a rule, I would have to put those same configurations into a cluster_config file in order to submit an sbatch job with the correct job specifications

Comment: Yes that's right. Basically just copy the example from the cluster docs and adapt to your needs